# Creating a modal box on page load

Tags: modal-dialog, load, box

I want to insert this modal box on my webpage, but I don't have the css of this code:

http://www.bootply.com/testazoid/14LH4kZul2#

Answer (score 0):

This modal from bootstrap. you need bootstrap JS and CSS

refer this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
  </script>
  

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: but I want it to load immediately on a page load.

Answer (score 0):

you'r might be looking for this

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```